# Unable to find chrome driver version 118 from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following error after running Selenium program

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 119
Current browser version is 118.0.5993.120 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I have downloaded version 119 to run selenium program and got above error but I cannot find version 118 from  https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. I need to download version 118

I got error and cannot find correct version of chrome driver

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are on Windows platform. Try the below [JSON end-points](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions.json) to download version `118` of `chromedriver.exe`.

For win32 platform - https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win32/chromedriver-win32.zip

For win 64 platform - https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/118.0.5993.70/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

Answer (score -1):

you can download 119 selenium chromedriver from here:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Comment: OP can already find version 119. They are looking for version _118_.